# objective-c  fetching array elements?

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays

this line of code gives the ans. 2 (which is right)

```
int def = arc4random() % 2;
NSLog(@"%@",[uniqueNumbers objectAtIndex:def]);
```

but when i use

```
int def = arc4random() % 2;
//NSLog(@"%@",[uniqueNumbers objectAtIndex:def]);
c1 = (int)[uniqueNumbers objectAtIndex:def];
NSLog(@"%d", c1);
```

it gives 115669616. where c1 is an integer. what is the problem?

Comment: Can you explain why you would do it a different way when the first way works?

Comment: because its not about just print the element of array, i used NSLog here just for understanding, anyway i solved this issue.

Comment: OK. I just couldn't understand the relevance of doing it another way when it worked already, but if it was just so you could understand the difference that makes sense.

Comment: OK, please dont mind and thanks for your interest in helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `c1 = [[uniqueNumbers objectAtIndex:def] intValue];`.

Answer (score 3):

You get an NSNumber instance back.
You need to unbox it by calling `intValue` on it, then you'll be good to go.

Johannes.

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray` holds *objects*, not integers. that cast to int is not valid.